# Custom Stream Utility

Tags: c++, windows, cout

I'm trying to create a printing utility, but need some help with the coding

To keep things simple for this question, we'll have an example utility. This example utility will changes the currently allocated windows console output color. Rather than doing `SetConsoleTextAttribute( blahblahblah )`, the utility will do this automatically, and in the printing statement.

e.g.:

```
std::ostream &SetPrintColorTo5B( std::ostream & stream )
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE ), 0x5B );
    return stream;
}
```

used like

```
std::cout << SetPrintColorTo5B << "Colored Text" << std::endl;
```

Now, how would I get this example function to accept parameters without messing up the whole stream?

e.g.:

```
std::ostream &SetPrintColor( std::ostream & stream, WORD wDesiredAttribute )
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE ), wDesiredAttribute );
    return stream;
}
```

so that it can be used like this:

```
std::cout << SetPrintColor << /* only this part is the parameter, and this shouldn't disrupt the stream after it */ 0x5B << "Colored Text" << std::endl;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please try to follow how current and existing stream manipulators work, which is like "functions" as in `... << SetPrintColor(SomeAttribute) << ...`

Answer (score 1):

I already have an alternative solution, but it's not as preferable as the function format :/

```
struct SetPrintColor
{
    WORD m_wDesiredAttribute ;
    SetPrintColor( WORD wDesiredAttribute ): m_wDesiredAttribute( wDesiredAttribute )
    { };
};

template < typename _Elem, typename _Traits > std::basic_ostream< _Elem, _Traits > &operator<<( std::basic_ostream< _Elem, _Traits > &stream, SetPrintColor& clr )
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), clr.m_wDesiredAttribute );
    return stream;
}
```

It would be used like `std::cout << SetPrintColor( 0x5B ) << "Colored text" << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

This way of working is also done by the standard library to configure if numbers need to be printed decimal or in hex.

In short, you need an instance of a distinct type to do so. For example:

```
struct MyOwnTag{};
constexpr static MyOwnTag Name{};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, MyOwnTag)
{
     // Do some code
     return stream;
 }
```

If you want to reuse the code over multiple streams, you could make it templated, or put the logic in the class and call it from within the streaming operator.

```
std::cout << Name << "text" << std::endl;
```

I'm not aware when this would return back to the old behavior, also not for `std::hex`.

If you somehow would like to force some reset. I would suggest wrapping the returned stream into a class where the destructor does that reset logic. Make sure to consider copy/move constructors and the destructor of the temporaries.

Comment: `I'm not aware when this would return back to the old behavior, also not for std::hex.`

  That's the issue; I'm not sure if it returns the behavior back to normal, and I know it doesn't for std::hex - you must use std::dec to change it back to normal.